# How to use B::Hooks to manipulate the perl parser

Tags: perl, xs

I'm looking to play with perl parser manipulation. It looks like the various `B::Hooks` modules are what people use. I was wondering:

1. Best place to start for someone who has no `XS` experience (yet). Any relevant blog posts?
2. How much work would be involved in creating a new operator, for example:

   `$a~>one~>two~>three`

`~>` would work like `->` but it would not try to call on `undef` and would instead simply return `undef` to LHS.

Although a source filter would work -- I'm more interested in seeing how you can manipulate the parser at a deeper level.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting feature. :)

Comment: I thought of it while getting annoyed doing `if( $dom->at('div')->at('h1')) { ` in Mojo::DOM and getting can't call undefined becasue `div` didn't exist :)

Comment: I have not figured this out yet but this looks promising: https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Utils

Comment: Have you considered using `autobox`? A very simple package with a fundamental `AUTOLOAD` routine would suffice. You wouldn't have a new operator, but adding all possible methods there are to `undef`. This would probably have terrible performance impacts. Like this: `use autobox UNDEF => 'SilentUndef'; … your code… package SilentUndef; sub AUTOLOAD {sub{}}`.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't seen autobox before. That looks like a good solution. Wouldn't it not be too bad performance wise because you are only 'autoboxing' undef (which shouldn't be called on anyway). But  right now I'm actually just trying to learn about the parser. The "tentatively call" thing above that avoids undef was just an example. BTW I now think I have to use: https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Hooks::OP::Check.

Comment: I never spent the time to figure out how to use B::Hooks to do this in perl5. I ended up doing it in perl6:  [Slang::Dotty](https://github.com/LLFourn/perl6-slang-dotty). In perl6 you can actually change the the syntax at runtime arbitrarily. Which is called a "slang".

Comment: When I did some XS in the past (which I completely forgot at this point) I started from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html 

For adding new operators, I would probably start from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Custom-Operators

Comment: @polettix That looks exactly what I need. I'd say using B::Hooks::OP::Check and hooking the custom operator OP would be the place to start. I won't be able to test this theory for a month or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can add infix operators (operators whose operands are before and after the operator), much less symbolic ones (as opposed to named operators), but you could write an an op checker that replaces method calls. This means you could cause `->foo` to behave differently. By writing your module as a pragma, you could limit the effect of your module to a lexical scope (e.g. `{ use mypragma; ...}`).